# Vuetify open select/autocomplete/combobox menu on focus

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetifyjs Autocomplete. I want to open its menu when user focuses on it using tab key from previous input. Below is the sample code

```
<div id="app">
<v-app>
    <v-container >
    <v-row >
        <v-col cols="12" md="4">
        <v-text-field label="Text Field"/>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" md="6">
        <v-autocomplete
            label="Autocomplete"
            :items="components"
            hint="need to open menu on focus, just like click" persistent-hint
        ></v-autocomplete>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </v-container>
</v-app>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
        components: [
          'Autocompletes', 'Comboboxes', 'Forms', 'Inputs', 'Overflow Buttons', 'Selects', 'Selection Controls', 'Sliders', 'Textareas', 'Text Fields',
        ],
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
</script>
```

I have also created a pen for this https://codepen.io/salalaslam/pen/YzzPajN

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because vuetify does not have the option you want, you must control it directly.

An `input` tag exists inside the `autocomplete` component. Specify focus event directly on this `input` tag.

Try this.

```html
// template

<v-autocomplete
    ref="autocomplete" 
    label="Autocomplete"
    :items="components"
    hint="need to open menu on focus, just like click" 
    persistent-hint
></v-autocomplete>
```

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    let autocompleteInput = this.$refs.autocomplete.$refs.input

    autocompleteInput.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus, true)
  },
  methods: {
    onFocus (e) {
      this.$refs.autocomplete.isMenuActive = true  // open item list
    }
  }
}
```

pen - https://codepen.io/kdydesign/pen/rNNadXN?editors=1111

Comment: Is there a solution for vuetify 3?

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of** digging to the low-level DOM, you can simply use Vue.js's **focus()** and **activateMenu()**

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" md="4">
      <v-text-field label="Text Field" @keydown.tab="focus" />
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" md="6">
      <v-autocomplete
        ref="aut"
        label="Autocomplete"
        :items="components"
        hint="need to open menu on focus, just like click"
        persistent-hint
      ></v-autocomplete>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: "center-six",
  data() {
    return {
      components: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    focus() {
      this.$refs["aut"].focus();
      this.$refs["aut"].activateMenu();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I have also created a **simple codePen** [VueJs Menu Activator](https://codepen.io/getmuluken/pen/yLbMzZj)

Comment: It seems this will give focus to the component, but not the actual input (ie. there will be no blinking cursor)

Comment: This worked for me (Vuetify 1.5.24). Autocomplete got focus with blinking cursor and menu opened.